# See who is on the same page in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am using CodeIgniter and I connect to a remote database. Only people who are in the table "users" are allowed to log in through `session`. Some of the tables in the DB can be edited on the site and a form sends the info to the Model (which then updates the info to the DB), what I want to do is the site to tell you who is on the edit page aswell like "John Doe is already editing this table". Is it possible to achieve it with session or something else?

Thankfull for any response.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do that. The simpliest way I can thing of right now is that on every edit to update a column on that table with the user id. After the user saves or cancels the entry, it resets that column to a default state.

Comment: Thats not exactly what I want, more like if you have ever seen a strategy like this in eshops : " Currently 25 customers are viewing this item". I want to do this but on my edit page: "Currently 1 administrator is on this page", whether only count or retrieve the admins name, either one is fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current URI with this method (be sure to load the URI helper):

```
$this->uri->uri_string();
```

Then I would keep a users table, since they're required to log in, you should already have this, then also keep a field which indicates whether they are logged in or not, then a nullable field indicating which page they are on. Then when you're on an admin/edit page, you can query all users which page = {admin/edit page}, and display which users are on this page.

Let me know if you have any other questions.